# How do I delete duplicate rows in this (mildly) complicated MySQL database situation?

Tags: php, mysql, database, greatest-n-per-group

Ok.  Please bear with me, I suck at explaining things.

I have a database of contact information that is gathered through a form on a website.  Obviously, people press submit more than once accidentally (or on purpose, but fixing is a different issue) so there are a LOT of duplicate rows in this database.

So, table1 holds contact information as such:

```
ID  |  date  |  unique ID code  |  first name, blah blah
1      stuff    20110101ba78b      joe
```

And table2 holds related data joined by the unique ID code field, as such:

```
ID  |  data  |  unique ID code
1      a        20110101ba78b
2      b        20110101ba78b
```

So, table2 holds multiple values for each person.  That's the structure of the table (and there are about a million rows in table2, so I'd rather not change the structure right now).

So my dilemma is this:  I know it's easy to make a temporary table and SELECT DISTINCT(all fields), but I want to keep the unique ID field for at least 1 of the duplicate rows.  If I keep the unique ID field though, it is unique for each row, even if the other data is exactly the same so SELECT DISTINCT(all fields) will not work, it will keep every row.  Hopefully I explained this thoroughly.  Please ask me for more information if needed.

EDIT:  I'm sure I could get rid of the ID field for each table, but as far as I'm concerned it's just .... there to be there.

Comment: Which set of values for Table2.ID and Table2.Data should be retained for the example Table2.Unique ID Code, and why?  Is part of the related data in Table2 a foreign key to other tables?  Will those other tables be left with unused data?

Comment: I know it's going to boil down to a PHP script to do this.  If I delete rows from table1, I will delete the related data from table2.  It's not mission critical data, just a tourist-related website.  I just included the structure of table2 to let you know how I use the unique ID field in table1.  I need one unique id per individual person in table1.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Don't forget to use the notation like '@Jonathan' to get the attention of the person who made a comment when you respond to a comment.  So, my question transfers from Table2 to Table1; how do you decide which of the multiple entries for a given Unique ID Code is the one to retain?  The most recently added one?  Or is there some other criterion?

Comment: @Jonathan, I know it sounds horrible, but it really doesn't matter.  From glancing at the duplicates, they're 99% identical.  And, if anything, they're spam entries.  So I'm not picky when it comes to that.  Thanks for the heads up on the tagging

Answer (score 1):

With the first clarification and a little reading between the lines, we can guess that it will be satisfactory to keep just the first or last entry for a given 'Unique ID Code' in Table1, where first or last means oldest or newest entry.  The queries are the same except for MAX vs MIN.  I'm assuming the 'date' column contains a fine enough (1 second or smaller) granularity that you don't get the same Unique ID Code twice in a time quantum; this is unlikely to be the case if the 'date' column really only contains a DATE (year, month, day) value, but probably is the case if you have a TIMESTAMP(3) and might well be the case with TIMESTAMP.

As always with SQL, build the query up in stages, nice and gently.

#### Find the newest entry for each Unique ID Code with multiple entries

```
SELECT Unique_ID_Code, MAX(date) AS Newest
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY Unique_ID_Code
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

#### Find the details for the Unique ID Code matching the newest entry

```
SELECT T1.*
  FROM Table1 AS T1
  JOIN (SELECT Unique_ID_Code, MAX(date) AS Newest
          FROM Table1
         GROUP BY Unique_ID_Code
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       ) AS M
    ON M.Unique_ID_Code = T1.Unique_ID_Code AND M.Newest = T1.Date
```

#### Now the tricky stuff

What you do next depends on how much you trust the transaction support in your DBMS and how big the Table1 is, and on whether you have ON DELETE CASCADE constraints on your foreign keys, and ...

You could create a temporary table with the rows selected by the second query above (MySQL syntax, I believe; other DBMS use different notations for this).

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE KeepTheseRows
    SELECT T1.*
      FROM Table1 AS T1
      JOIN (SELECT Unique_ID_Code, MAX(date) AS Newest
              FROM Table1
             GROUP BY Unique_ID_Code
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
           ) AS M
        ON M.Unique_ID_Code = T1.Unique_ID_Code AND M.Newest = T1.Date;
```

then delete all the rows from Table1 that match the duplicate unique ID codes:

```
DELETE FROM Table1
    WHERE Unique_ID_Code IN (SELECT Unique_ID_Code FROM KeepTheseRows);
```

and then reinstate the rows to be kept:

```
INSERT INTO Table
    SELECT * FROM KeepTheseRows;
```

You may need to defer constraint checking while this happens, or you may need to drop the foreign key constraints while this occurs.  You need to worry about activity while this operation occurs; it would be best if people were not inserting rows into Table1 while this is running.  If they are modifying the table as you run, you may find that you have to do the processing several times.  You should add a unique constraint to Table1.Unique_ID_Code just as soon as possible so you don't get into the mess again.  (And don't forget to re-enable any deferred constraints or recreate and dropped foreign keys.)

There probably are other equivalent ways to do this; this relies only on standard (SQL-92) SQL apart from the temporary table notation.

Experiment with a copy of your production database.

Comment: tried your third query and received this: Error
SQL query: 

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE KeepTheseRows SELECT * 
FROM contact_info AS T1
JOIN (


SELECT uniq_id, MAX( DATE ) AS Newest
FROM contact_info
GROUP BY uniq_id
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
) AS M ON M.uniq_id = T1.uniq_id
AND M.Newest = T1.Date
MySQL said: 

#1060 - Duplicate column name 'uniq_id'

Comment: @meinemitternacht: Oh - bother...that's why you test!  'SELECT T1.*' instead of 'SELECT *' in the outer query.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I also just noticed something.  I think I wasn't clear about it, but there is a unique constraint on the Unique_ID_Code field.  There are no problems with that being duplicated.  It's randomly generated in the PHP script.  The problem is the other data in the table is the same for multiple unique ID's.

Comment: @meinemitternacht: then I no longer understand the question - but the technique shown can be applied to any table with partial or completely duplicate rows with appropriate adjustments to the sets of columns used.  For an extreme case, see my answer to [SO 4762724](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762724/highest-appearance-of-a-value-within-each-group/4769995#4769995).  The objective there was not removing duplicates, but the `SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM Table GROUP BY ...columns...` technique works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This to update Table 2 to use the lowest uniqueID number for identical contact info:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET Table2.uniqueID = (
    SELECT T1.UniqueID
    FROM Table1 T1, Table1 T2
    WHERE T1.unique ID < T2.unique ID
    AND T1.firstname = T2.firstname
    AND T1.date = T2.date
    AND T1.blah, blah = T2.blah, blah
) 
WHERE Table2.uniqueID = (
    Select T1.UniqueID
    from Table1 T1, CopyOfTable1 T2
    where T1.firstname = T2.firstname
    and T1.date = T2.date
    and T1.blah, blah = T2.blah, blah
);
```

This to remove all except ONE (with the lowest uniqueID) duplicate contact info records:

```
delete T1
from Table1 T1, CopyOfTable1 T2
where T1.unique ID > T2.unique ID
and T1.firstname = T2.firstname
and T1.date = T2.date
and T1.blah, blah = T2.blah, blah
```

Comment: I tried an approach like this and the problem is the unique ID field.  If I include it in any form or fashion, all rows are unique.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you here, either. There are 100,000+ rows in table1, and well over a million rows in table2.  Am I going to go through each duplicate portion of table1 manually?

Comment: i think the 1st statement deletes all the highest uniqueID and keeps the lowest to be used but the second statement uses the highest. editing again to change sign...